# Fully simplifying $\sqrt{13+2\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{20}\right)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this statement:

> Simplify this: $\sqrt{13+2\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{20}\right)}$

I know how to simplify roots like $\sqrt{a \pm k\sqrt{b}}$, But i don't know how to simplify this.

Any hint for an elegant solution is appreciated.

Comment: See [http://oeis.org/A195384](http://oeis.org/A195384)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to simplify totally the square root is notice that inside of its there is an expression that can be rewrited in the form: $a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ac=(a+b+c)^2$
So, we have to determine $a,b,c$ and to do this, I can use the duble product, in fact:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
ab=\sqrt2
\\ac=-\sqrt{20}
\\bc=-\sqrt{10}
\end{matrix}\right.$$
From this, I obtain: $$c=\sqrt{10}, b=-1,a=-\sqrt{2}$$
The expression becomes: $$\sqrt{13+2\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{20}\right)}=\sqrt{(-\sqrt{2}-1+\sqrt{10})^2}=(-\sqrt{2}-1+\sqrt{10})$$

Answer (score 4):

Notice that $$(-\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z})^2=x+y+z-2\sqrt{xy}+2\sqrt{yz}-2\sqrt{xz}$$
So $$\sqrt{x+y+z-2\sqrt{xy}+2\sqrt{yz}-2\sqrt{xz}}=-\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}$$

In your case on comparision you have $x+y+z=13$, $xy=20, zx=10, yz=2.$ So you get $xyz=20$, then $x=10,y=2,z=1$, Hence the answer is $\sqrt{10} -\sqrt{2}- \sqrt{1}.$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
13 + 2(\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{10} - \sqrt{20}) = (1 + \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{10})^{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have one doubt that is: What was your thought to get that hint? And since $1+\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{10} < 0$, therefore $|1+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{10}| = -1 -\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{10}$ that is the answer.

Comment: My answer is based on the following algebraic identity
$$(a+b+c)^{2} = a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} + 2ab + 2ac + 2bc$$